# Eclipse 2019-09: No convert to maven menu item

Tags: eclipse, maven

I did a fresh install of the Eclipse J2EE, into a new directory, and the project menu looks very different to what it did before in 2019-06. For example there is no Convert menu item, hence I cannot convert a dynamic web app to a maven format. And one menu item seems to be broken, it reads %fragment.menu.srv.

With my old projects I can use maven, git,.. everything. Just the convert is missing. So either the convert-functionality got moved and I can't find it or....

Any hints?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly enough, pointing to a new workspace did the trick.
(see preferences and search for "workspace" -> choose at startup)